# Is there way to trigger data lake analytics job by event?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

Is there way to trigger data lake analytics job by next event:
"When data/*event* came to the event hub" it triggers job. 
It's not necessarily event hub, but i want to trigger the job and somehow pass data *(as json for example)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's not necessarily event hub, but i want to trigger the job and somehow pass data (as json for example)

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using azure web jobs(you could also using [eventhub trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support) or [queue trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues)) and using azure data lake analytics net SDK to achieve your requirement.

Before you begin using azure data lake analytics net SDK, you need firstly register a AD application for your application to ask the token(using client id and secret) to access the ADLA.

Registry an App in Azure AD and create service principle for it. More detail steps about how to registry app and get access token please refer to [document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

Notice:Do forget add permission with your AD group to access the data lake, more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data).

After doing this, you could use below codes to create a web jobs which will triggered by the queue (or event hub) to create a new job in the data lake analytics to run your script.

Codes as below:

Notice: You need install the below package from Nuget:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC (preview)
Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics
Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 
Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication
```

Function.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store;
using Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Analytics.Models;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace WebJob1
{
    public class Functions
    {
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            string adlaAccountName = "adlaAccountName";
            string subscriptionId = "yoursubscriptionid";

            string domain = "tenantid";
            var armTokenAudience = new Uri(@"https://management.core.windows.net/");
            var adlTokenAudience = new Uri(@"https://datalake.azure.net/");
            var aadTokenAudience = new Uri(@"https://graph.windows.net/");

            // ----------------------------------------
            // Perform authentication to get credentials
            // ----------------------------------------


            // NON - INTERACTIVE WITH SECRET KEY
            string clientId = "clientId";
            string secretKey = "clientsecretKey";
            var armCreds = GetCredsServicePrincipalSecretKey(domain, armTokenAudience, clientId, secretKey);
            var adlCreds = GetCredsServicePrincipalSecretKey(domain, adlTokenAudience, clientId, secretKey);
            var aadCreds = GetCredsServicePrincipalSecretKey(domain, aadTokenAudience, clientId, secretKey);

            // INTERACTIVE WITH CACHE
            //var tokenCache = new TokenCache();
            //tokenCache.BeforeAccess = BeforeTokenCacheAccess;
            //tokenCache.AfterAccess = AfterTokenCacheAccess;
            //var armCreds = GetCredsInteractivePopup(domain, armTokenAudience, tokenCache, PromptBehavior.Auto);
            //var adlCreds = GetCredsInteractivePopup(domain, adlTokenAudience, tokenCache, PromptBehavior.Auto);
            //var aadCreds = GetCredsInteractivePopup(domain, aadTokenAudience, tokenCache, PromptBehavior.Auto);

            // INTERACTIVE WITHOUT CACHE
            // var armCreds = GetCredsInteractivePopup(domain, armTokenAudience, PromptBehavior.Auto);
            // var adlCreds = GetCredsInteractivePopup(domain, adlTokenAudience, PromptBehavior.Auto);
            // var aadCreds = GetCredsInteractivePopup(domain, aadTokenAudience, PromptBehavior.Auto);


            // NON-INTERACTIVE WITH CERT
            // string clientId = "<service principal / application client ID>";
            // var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"<path to (PFX) certificate file>", "<certificate password>");
            // var armCreds = GetCredsServicePrincipalCertificate(domain, armTokenAudience, clientId, certificate);
            // var adlCreds = GetCredsServicePrincipalCertificate(domain, adlTokenAudience, clientId, certificate);
            // var aadCreds = GetCredsServicePrincipalCertificate(domain, aadTokenAudience, clientId, certificate);

            // ----------------------------------------
            // Create the REST clients using the credentials
            // ----------------------------------------

            var adlaAccountClient = new DataLakeAnalyticsAccountManagementClient(armCreds);
            adlaAccountClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            var adlsAccountClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(armCreds);
            adlsAccountClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            var adlaCatalogClient = new DataLakeAnalyticsCatalogManagementClient(adlCreds);
            var adlaJobClient = new DataLakeAnalyticsJobManagementClient(adlCreds);
            var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(adlCreds);

            var graphClient = new GraphRbacManagementClient(aadCreds);
            graphClient.TenantID = domain;

            // ----------------------------------------
            // Perform operations with the REST clients
            // ----------------------------------------

            var script = @" your script ";
            var jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var properties = new USqlJobProperties(script);
            var parameters = new JobInformation("test1", JobType.USql, properties, priority: 1, degreeOfParallelism: 1, jobId: jobId);
            //Create and submit new job
            var jobInfo = adlaJobClient.Job.Create(adlaAccountName, jobId, parameters);
        }

        // The interactive samples reuse Azure PowerShell's client ID
        // For production code you should use your own client ids
        private static string azure_powershell_clientid = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2";

        /*
         *  Interactive: User popup
         *  (no token cache to reuse/save session state)
         */
        private static ServiceClientCredentials GetCredsInteractivePopup(string domain, Uri tokenAudience, PromptBehavior promptBehavior = PromptBehavior.Auto)
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            // The client id comes from Azure PowerShell
            // for production code you should use your own client id

            var clientSettings = new ActiveDirectoryClientSettings
            {
                ClientId = azure_powershell_clientid,
                ClientRedirectUri = new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
                PromptBehavior = promptBehavior
            };

            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = tokenAudience;

            var creds = UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync(domain, clientSettings, serviceSettings).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return creds;
        }

        /*
         *  Interactive: User popup
         *  (using a token cache to reuse/save session state)
         */
        private static ServiceClientCredentials GetCredsInteractivePopup(string domain, Uri tokenAudience, TokenCache tokenCache, PromptBehavior promptBehavior = PromptBehavior.Auto)
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            var clientSettings = new ActiveDirectoryClientSettings
            {
                ClientId = azure_powershell_clientid,
                ClientRedirectUri = new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
                PromptBehavior = promptBehavior
            };

            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = tokenAudience;

            var creds = UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync(domain, clientSettings, serviceSettings, tokenCache).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return creds;
        }



        /*
         *  Interactive: Device code login
         *  NOT YET SUPPORTED by Azure's .NET SDK authentication library
         */
        private static ServiceClientCredentials GetCredsDeviceCode()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Azure SDK's .NET authentication library doesn't support device code login yet.");
        }

        /*
         *  Non-interactive: Service principal / application using a secret key
         *  Setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal#create-service-principal-with-password
         */
        private static ServiceClientCredentials GetCredsServicePrincipalSecretKey(string domain, Uri tokenAudience, string clientId, string secretKey)
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = tokenAudience;

            var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain, clientId, secretKey, serviceSettings).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return creds;
        }

        /*
         *  Non-interactive: Service principal / application using a certificate
         *  Setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal#create-service-principal-with-self-signed-certificate
         */
        private static ServiceClientCredentials GetCredsServicePrincipalCertificate(string domain, Uri tokenAudience, string clientId, X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            var clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);
            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = tokenAudience;

            var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentWithCertificateAsync(domain, clientAssertionCertificate, serviceSettings).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return creds;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]